# Count records for each instance of while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a count for each instance of a while loop.  So far all I can find is how to keep the counter running, so for example.

```
$counter = 0;
while(..) {
      $counter++; // or $counter = $counter + 1;
}

echo $counter;
```

What I'm looking for is more to count the number of records each time the while loop runs, so more like this.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $date = $row['date'];

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date = $date ";
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($r);

    echo "There are ".$count." records for ."$date.".";

}
```

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect to see at the end? It looks to me like you need to combine your two code snippets together

Comment: `$count += mysqli_num_rows($r);` ... note the `+` And move the `echo` to after the `while`... or something. No idea what your endgame is here.

Comment: If you put `$date` in quotes it would probably work like that i.e.`WHERE \`date\` = '$date'`

Comment: So you have one while loop and inside you want to select data just to count them? What is inside $row? Can't you make something like `SELECT date, count(*)as count FROM your_table GROUP BY date;` then in your while loop just do `echo "There are ".$row['count']." records for ."$row['date']."."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably be better off changing the outer SQL to do the count in one go...

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) as countForDate
    FROM table
    GROUP BY date
```

(plus whatever other WHERE clause you may have).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  That does work to count the total records all together.  That outputs 2018-09-14 with 4 records.  I'm trying to get the total count each time the while loop runs.  So if I have 3 records that were entered on 2018-09-14 and 1 record that was entered on 2018-09-21. I'm trying to have the output like this. 2018-09-14 has 3 records and 2018-09-21 has a total of 1 record.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you very much.  That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Querying database in a cycle is always a bad practice.

If I understand well, you are trying to get dates by one query and then you use another query to select rows by date.

If you can't use JOIN to combine this queries, you may collect array of dates, implode it and use it with IN and GROUP BY statements.

```
$dates = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dates[] = $row['date'];
}

$in = implode("','");
$sql = "SELECT date, COUNT(*) as date_count FROM table WHERE date IN ('".$in."') GROUP BY date";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "There are ".$row['date_count']." records for ".$row['date'].".";
}
```

So now you have only two queries instead of many